# how to change the controller name in zend with under score or dash?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, zend-framework2

1. how to change the controller name in URL in zend-framework ?.
2. if my URL is
   http://www.diamondhedge.com/dev_new/public/diamondeducation/carat but
   i want to change to like this
   http://www.diamondhedge.com/dev_new/public/diamond-education/carat.

Comment: What framework are you using, ZF1 or ZF2 or CodeIgniter? this is lacking any information that anyone can use to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change the controller name to change the url structure, you can change the route configuration though here is an example
in your module.config.php under the routes put something like this

```
'myroute'     => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'       => '/dev_new/public/diamond-education/carat.',
                    'defaults'    => array(
                        'controller' => 'Module\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'myaction',

                    )
                )
            ),
```